# How to validate url using regex but without http and https

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to validate url i am using this regex

```
!(Uri.tryParse(val)?.hasAbsolutePath ?? false)
```

i entered google.com but it return false when we do not add http or https if i use regex please provide me i dont know how to create regex for this

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex I came up with:

```
(?:https?://)?\S+\.\S+\.\S+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NpqDbXx2ULCLg4Cd)

It does have a problem tho, it matches anything that isn't a whitespace, which means that something like this:

www.my/w(ebs"i%t&e.net

will be accepted. You can check [this website](https://www.urlregex.com/) if you want to look at better regexes for URLs

Here is how you can check a regex on dart:

```
RegExp myRegex = RegExp('my regex');

bool isURL(String url) {
  return myRegex.hasMatch(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the [validators](https://pub.dev/packages/validators) package and try `isURL("google.com")`. This helped me.